# Finding kth smallest element in array using QuickSelect. Why we should substract L(leftmost index) from POS(position of random partition)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort, quickselect

```
// function for finding Kth smallest element
int kthSmallest(int arr[], int l, int r, int k)
{
    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1)
    {
        int pos = randPart(arr, l, r); // position of random partition
        // now compairing pos with Kth position
        if (pos == k - 1)
            return arr[pos];
        else if (pos > k - 1)
            return kthSmallest(arr, l, pos - 1, k);
        return kthSmallest(arr, pos + 1, r, k);
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}
```

It gives random output:

```
PS C:\Users\anmol\Desktop\c++projectwork> g++ .\450\3.-KthMinOrMaxEle.cpp
PS C:\Users\anmol\Desktop\c++projectwork> ./a
enter n and k:
6 3
enter array elements:
7 10 4 3 20 15
answer element:2147483647
```

The above is my code but solution code has some difference.
Solution code is as:

```
int kthSmallest(int arr[], int l, int r, int k){
    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1){
        int pos = randPart(arr, l, r); // position of random partition
        if (pos - l == k - 1){ // pos-l not pos why?
            return arr[pos];
        }
        else if (pos - l > k - 1)
            return kthSmallest(arr, l, pos - 1, k);
        return kthSmallest(arr, pos + 1, r, k - pos + l - 1);
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}
```

Why my code is not working because i think randomPartition function(randPart()) return pos index according to orignal array indexing and k-1 is also  according to orignal array indexing, So why there is need to convert them?

Comment: If you are searching in the right half, then you don't need to find the kth largest element here 

 return kthSmallest(arr, pos + 1, r, k); 

You might need to find the  ( k - (pos -l + 1) largest element

Comment: Can you try with this change whether it works

Comment: Just a tip, instead of writing your own algorithms, first check what's available in the standard library. E.g. have a look at : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element. This way you can use heavily tested code which will reduce the number of bugs in your program.

Comment: The code is pure C. It has nothing to do with C++